# Where can I post a UI design for feedback from the community?

Tags: gui-design, feedback, guidance

I'd like to post a design I'm working on to get some feedback and suggestions from the community. Is this site a good place or are there other better suited sites?

Comment: Here's a new place (2017) where people will do usability testing of your website / design / user-interface, and give feedback: https://usability.testing.exchange  (I'm developing it. People might not want to install & test mobile phone apps though, but if you have a sketch / wireframe design, and post a link to it, then that should work fine.)

Answer (score 5):

One useful site is  [FiveSecondTest](http://fivesecondtest.com/).

It's quick and easy (and free) for people to leave comments about your UI. I do believe there is a charge for submitting your own UI designs for feedback though. I have only ever used it to take part in tests, not to get feedback on my own designs so I can't vouch for how useful the feedback recieved is.

Answer (score 3):

[Forrst.com](http://forrst.com/) is an emerging UI design community site that I have come to enjoy. Give it a whirl.

Comment: Looks cool. Have you got an invite?

Comment: Yep: https://forrst.com/signup?i=holidays2k11

Answer (score 2):

If you have a well defined question, than you can get answers here as well from professionals. But avoid asking tooo broad questions, like do you like the design, rather ask seperate questions about the menu, search bar, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [www.usertesting.com](http://www.usertesting.com).

You get a video of a user talking about your webpage. You choose the questions they answer.

Downside is it's a little on the expensive side, at $29-$39 per test. However I think getting feedback from users can be more much helpful that just getting feedback from other designers.

Answer (score 1):

For a starter you can post it here and users of UX stackexchange will do the honor to help you with your design feedbacks.

Another website community you can post your design is [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com). It is a good design community wherein you can share and have some feedbacks from awesome designers all around the world.

Comment: What if I'm not a designer? I'm a web developer that occasionally dabbles in design. I have created a wizard and it doesn't feel 'right'! the wizard doesn't seem to fit with the rest of the site. Where do I go for advice on that? :(

Answer (score 0):

For specific UX questions this site here is a great resource, but it is not the best place to go for general "what do you think of my design?" questions. For quick feedback I like [fivesecondtest](http://www.fivesecondtest.com), for longer answers you may want to try [conceptfeedback](http://www.conceptfeedback.com) (it's a little bit focused on the graphical side but you can get valuable UX advice there as well).

Answer (score 0):

[Forrst.com](http://forrst.com) and [Dribbble.com](http://dribbble.com) (on invitations) are the most used online resources. Because to really have feedback from a community you first need a strong community. And since those two sites are here for a while now, you'll get precious feedback. I can add [Behance.net](http://www.behance.net) and [Lovedsgn.com](http://lovedsgn.com/) that are also well spread among the community.